# Bash environment variable from Ruby Script by a Bash Script

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell

**Short description:**

I have a bash script `weather.sh` that export variable in to bash Environment variable, but this variables appear only in context of this script, and is not reachable from terminal where I fired this script `./weather.sh`. I have to retype content of this script to make variable available.

How to avoid retyping?

**UPD Answer:**
Instead of `./weather.sh` fire `source weather.sh`.

**Detail description:**

- I have a token file, a plain text file with one line that contains HTTP token for request. File name is `WEATHER_TOKEN`
- Also I have a bash script file `weather.sh` I created for automate exporting `WEAHTER_TOKEN` into **ENV** variable. This file have several lines that check that the variable is successfully exported.

`WEATHER_TOKEN=$(cat 'WEATHER_TOKEN')
    export WEATHER_TOKEN
    echo "The weather token is: $WEATHER_TOKEN"
    ruby -e 'p "Ruby Reads WEATHER_TOKEN too: %s" % ENV["WEATHER_TOKEN"]'`

- When I call `./weather.sh` I got an output that succesfully prints TOKEN twice.
- **BUT** when I call a ruby script `nil == ENV["WEATHER_TOKEN"]` and when I type `echo "$WEATHER_TOKEN"` I got an empty string.
- And I have to retype all content of the `weather.sh` into terminal to have the variable accessable.

How to avoid retyping `wether.sh` into the terminal, but run the `weather.sh` such way so it creates `WEATHER_TOKEN` var for my ruby scripts?

**UPD Answer:**
Instead of `./weather.sh` fire `source weather.sh`.

Comment: Instead of running the script as `./weather.sh` do `source weather.sh` and see if its fixing the problem

Comment: @indian, It is  not duplicated, because I asked about **NEW** way to fire scripts. Not about difference in ways.

Comment: @DmitryDmitriev Whilst that question may not have been phrased in exactly the way you worded it, the accepted answer fully describes your problem: *:"`./script.sh` just runs the script in a subprocess, and any variables which are assigned disappear after the script is done."* What you were doing was `export`ing variables **in a sub-process**, therefore they were never made available to your ruby script.

Comment: So in other words, the answer to your question has not really got anything to do with ruby; you just need to understand what `source` and `export` actually do, in the context of sub-processes.